# Sorting layers having no effect at all

Tags: sorting, unity-game-engine, layer

I currently have a scene set up in Unity2D where sorting layers of any kind have no effect at all.

I start with 3 panels on the screen (attached to a canvas). The panels have some images as children. Then I position them such that there is some overlap between them. From there I attach a Sorting Group component to them, and then run my game.

From there I've tried everything I can think of to alter the sorting layers and have one of the back panels appear at the front but to no avail. I've tried altering the Sorting Group layers, the Unity layers, and the Z position.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add code examples showing what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 4):

I believe Sorting Group is a UI component. It's used for parent game objects of sprite children.

What you want is to add the "Canvas" Component (Not to be confused with the main UI canvas) to each of your panels. Then make sure Override sorting is checked. Then put a number in for the order. Larger numbers are in front of smaller numbers.

Comment: That did the trick! But it broke my Event Triggers (Pointer Enter and Pointer Exit). The Event Triggers still work though if I remove the Canvas component. Is there a way to have both?

Comment: Solved this new issue by adding a Graphic Raycaster component (in case anyone in the future has this issue).

Comment: Can you elaborate where I'd find "Override sorting"? I only have "Sort Order" on my Canvas.

Comment: It's 2023 and you're still helping people. Hats off!

Comment: Buddy you saved me!! Since adding the Canvas component to Override Sorting was causing my buttons to not get clicked, I disabled the Graphic Raycaster of other canvases including the parent, and added them individually to the buttons. Thanks a lot!